# mathjax and opening in new tab

Tags: support, mathjax

So, I almost always open a question in a new tab by right clicking the question title.  But, if a title only has MathJax, I can't do this.  For example:

[Are there unique solutions for $n=\sum_{j=1}^{g(k)} a_j^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103432/82322212-78-72423222)

Right click it and you get various MathJax related options only.  This is a small problem, but just thought I'd bring it up.  Is it fixable?

By the way I'm using Firefox 9 something inside of Windows 7, in case that matters.

Comment: This may depend on OS and Browser. On Firefox 8 on Linux, when I right click the MathJax'd hyperlink, I get the usual context menu **over** the MathJax menu. So I can in fact open in new tab/new window and what not, but _not_ access the MathJax menu until I click elsewhere to get rid of the usual right-click menu.

Comment: Previously on Meta: [MathJax menu obliterates link menu when the entire link is LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1204/856). I suggested that titles not be written entirely in TeX for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is not the answer you want, but you should be able to still open the link in a new tab by middle clicking or Ctrl-clicking. See [here](http://www.mouserunner.com/FF_Shortcuts1Printable.html). I'm on a Mac so I can't test this in your setup, but it looks legit.